# Simple Prototype creator

Tags: ios, wireframe

i am looking for simple prototype/wireframe/mockup creator, with that i can show flow of any application to designing team.

I have used [Jutinmind](http://www.justinmind.com/) but found that a little bit time taking.

i want simple one that won't take much time

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a kickstarter being funded that would meet your needs nicely http://www.kickstarter.com/projects/appseed/appseed-turn-sketches-into-functioning-prototypes